# Is there any way to assign a pointer and increment a counter, atomically, without locks?

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic

Given these as an example

```
struct MyObj {
    void * x;
    int counter;
};

std::atomic<MyObj *> globalSourceThatGetsChangedByOtherThreads = ...;
```

This is what I would like to do:

```
void someCode() {

  //begin atomic
  MyObj *dest = globalSourceThatGetsChangedByOtherThreads.load();
  globalSourceThatGetsChangedByOtherThreads->counter++;
  //end atomic
}
```

I was trying to be clever with an x86 assembler call, but that wasn't working.

Comment: If you have a new CPU, check out Lock Elision  http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2579227 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to use c11 atomics, but I think you mean something like this.  I use unions all the time to change multiple fields using atomic compare and swap.  Another technique when working with pointers is take advantage of how much address space is actually used by your OS.  Windows 64 bit only uses 44 bits of address and that is 8 byte aligned, meaing you only need 41 bits to hold a pointer.  This frees up 23 bits for counters and other fields.  Here I'm assuming 64 bit addressing but you only really need 48 bits of address space.  That frees up 16 bits for a counter:

```
typedef unsigned int64 QWORD;
union { 
  // This struct is what we actually work with
  struct { 
    QWORD m_x : 48,  // most os don't use the full 64 bit address space...
          m_c : 16;
  };
  // This is what we compare and swap.
  QWORD   m_n64;  
  // constructor to make the code clean.  This doesn't use memory barriers
  // so depending on your architecture, you might need a barrier.  With x64 and 
  // windows the barrier on the compare and swap has always been sufficient.
  MyObj(const volatile MyObj &r) volatile { m_n64 = r.m_n64; }
} MyObj;


while (1) {
  // its not clear to me if pOld will change or the data at pOld or both, so i
  // put volatile on both
  volatile MyObj* volatile pOld = globalSourceThatGetsChangedByOtherThreads.load();
  MyObj Old(*pOld), New(Old);
  // set lots of fields!
  New.m_x = (QWORD)somepointer;
  New.m_c++;
  // assume CompareAndSwap64 returns true if the 64 bit number was successfully swapped 
  if (CompareAndSwap64(pOld, &Old, &New))
    break;
  // if we get here, rare, we had a race.  Try again.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
 struct MyObj {
        void * x;
        std::atomic_int counter;
 };

 std::atomic<MyObj *> globalSourceThatGetsChangedByOtherThreads = ...;


void someCode() {
  MyObj *dest;
  while (true) {
    dest = globalSourceThatGetsChangedByOtherThreads.load();
    //globalSourceThatGetsChangedByOtherThreads could have changed between above and below
    dest->counter++;
    // check
    if (dest == globalSourceThatGetsChangedByOtherThreads.load())
        break;
    else
        dest->counter--;
  }
  dest->x->doSomethingReadOnly();
  dest->counter--;
}
```